# Changing styles in Zend Framework 2 pagination

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework, pagination

I am trying to replace the default style in Zend Framework 2's pagination to use Twitter Boostrap's pagination style. I am having trouble though with changing the style, as some of the elements are off and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
    <nav>
<ul class="pagination">
<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>
<!-- Previous page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
   <li class="previous"><a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->previous)); ?>">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>
<?php else: ?>
  <li class="previous disabled">&laquo;</span> 
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Numbered page links -->
<?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
  <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
    <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $page)); ?>">
        <?php echo $page; ?>
    </a></li>
  <?php else: ?>
   <?php echo $page; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!-- Next page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
  <li class="next"><a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->next)); ?>">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>
<?php else: ?>
  <li class="next disabled">&raquo;</li
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

If it helps, here is a screenshot of what I am trying to say.

[image]

As you can see, the elements are off. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

nevermind fixed it, was not using the right attributes.